# How to wrap a gift so it doesn't look like the gift?

Tags: christmas

I need to wrap a gift but it has a really obvious shape and they would know what it is. Is there a way that I can wrap it so that they won't know what it is till they open it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a cardboard box larger than the gift, and gift wrap the box.

If you don't have a large box, you could -- depending on the gift -- place smaller, disposable objects such as foam cups or crumpled newspaper around the gift to alter its shape under the wrapping paper.

Comment: Also if the gift is not fragile include some other objects in the box to provide a misleading weight/sound when picked up or shaken...

Answer (score 6):

**You can wrap them in the following methods:**

- Use cardboard or Newspaper. This can be done by crumpling the newspaper around the item or by plainly putting them in a cardboard box.

  - Putting them in cleaned cereal boxes is a good method and really small gifts can be concealed in origami. Its kind of tricky to fold them in though.

**For something more fancy looking:**

[Buzzfeed.com](http://www.buzzfeed.com/alessiasantoro/it-just-gets-ripped-open-in-the-end-anyways#.rhM1qK6bq):

[image]

- Wrap them in Balls of Yarn. This is good as you can have any colour of yarn, but retrieving them can be tricky and wrapping them can be trickier.

[image]

- Folding the gift into a sweater or other article of clothing. This is good for books and other items. Wrapping them in clothe also works. The buzzfeed.com article wraps them in scarves.

  - This is good for giving two gifts.

[image]

- This article also shows putting gifts into a sweater sleeves. Not very concealing, but cute.

[image]

- Use paper or plastic bags. Paper bags are more decorative. You shouldn't add the buttons and such because that totally gives it away.

  - A large black bag would work, but be sure to let the air stay in it.

---

**Other Ideas**

- Putting them in Lego brick boxes is good for Lego fans and kids. But it may take a lot of bricks.
- Taking multicolored cups or any cup, especially mugs and putting the gift inside. You can make a whole table of gifts by putting other gifts into dishes.

  - Garbage cans and other storage boxes, may help.
- Putting the gift in jars with custom or large labels helps. You can even use cans, but be careful of the sharp edges.

***Basically taking any container that wouldn't be expected works. Containers like lunch boxes, non-clear containers, etc.***

Answer (score 4):

Often times I have used multiple boxes wrapped within each other (like the classic "[Russian Nesting Dolls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll)") to mask the appearance of a smaller, more recognizable gift. Not only does this add to the illusion of what the gift is, or might be (and to the work for you, however), it adds a bit of fun to the process of opening the gift.

If the gift is either too large for the nesting theory, I have taken parts of boxes an taped or "added" to the length before. This makes the box either longer, wider or taller... sometimes even odd shaped if you care to be "silly" with the process.

I have also been known to add sections of the inner cardboard tubes to the gift in odd places from either toilet paper, paper towel, or even wrapping paper rolls. This interesting shape helps to mask the appearance easily. And, you can place a few rocks, pieces of candy, change, small jingle bells or the like within the tubes so they "rattle" a bit within the void and this too adds to the subterfuge of what the gift may be.

As a last resort, I have wrapped a picture of the larger gift within a small package before to entirely throw the individual off. Not only is this a great trick, it saves on a TON of paper and tape if the gift is quite large. Imagine the surprise a person would have if they opened up a photo of their new bike, new ice skates, a laptop/tablet, Playstation or Xbox...especially if the box was the size of an earring box!

Answer (score 3):

Turn it into an Easter Egg hunt. Place a card under the Xmas tree. Inside the card give a clue as to where the present can be found. In the next place hide a box wrapped in Xmas paper - in there place another clue to where the real present can be found.

Comment: how ironic to use Easter Egg Hunt on Christmas.